# Mimimum and Minimal element of an ordered set

Tags: order-theory

During study of ordered sets,I gone through 'minimal element' and 'minimum element' of a set.
Can someone explain the difference between them with examples?

Many thanks and regards,

Answer (score 1):

**Minimum:** minimum is an element that is less than all other elements of the set.

**Minimal:** minimal is an element such that there is no element less than that.

Here are some observations that may help:

- The main difference between these two is that *minimal* cannot be compared with all the elements of the set. However, among those that can be compared to is minimum
- *Minimum* is an element that can be compared to all the elements of the set and is less than all of them.
- Each *minimum* need to be *minimal* but the reverse is not true.
- There may be several *minimals* in a set while *minimum* is always unique.